# Login with Google for nginx

Tags: nginx, g-suite, google

I have a nginx server serving protected resources. The last thing I want to do is manage password reset requests, so I was looking at [Login with Google](https://developers.google.com/+/).

They have examples for PHP, Java, JavaScript etc., but not for Apache or nginx. How can I configure nginx to swap out basic authentication with the [Login with Google](https://developers.google.com/+/) functionality?

Some proxied systems behind depend on the %REMOTE_USER% variable, so I need that one preserved.
Help is appreciated.

**Update**
To clarify: I have a set of services (a tomcat, a node.js, a couchdb, a vert.x, some python) that sit behind the web server, that might or might not authorize a user to interact with them. They all have in common, that they can receive identity information from the web tier.

So what I do in the web tier: specify - "authenticated users only" (which is a *authorization* setting, I "reuse" to trigger the ***authentication*** mechanism).

Once the user is authenticated, that identity information is passed on. For an example with basic authentication and CouchDB, check [this blog entry](http://www.wissel.net/blog/d6plinks/SHWL-948KKJ). I can do the same in nginx, but the task here is <strike>to burden someone else with keeping a password secret</strike> using identities established with an outside provider.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you could run the [oauth2_proxy](https://github.com/bitly/oauth2_proxy) in front of your web app.

> A reverse proxy and static file server that provides authentication using Providers (Google, GitHub, and others) to validate accounts by email, domain or group.

Comment: The documentation describes how to use it with the nginx auth_request directive. That’s exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 2):

While you can *theoretically* implement OAuth on the webserver level (example: http://chairnerd.seatgeek.com/oauth-support-for-nginx-with-lua/), it's generally a pretty bad idea. There are examples for server-side languages because that's where you should implement it - in your code, not your server.

Comment: And why is that a bad idea? Just imagine for a moment you have a web server in front of a set of services. Then you need to pass credentials left and right. Letting the "guy at the door" decide who comes in or not instead of checking at the table, the bar and the dance floor sounds rather reasonable?

Comment: stwissel - you are confusing authentication with authorization. Which tier you should implement the components in depends a lot on the specifics of your application, architecture, development model....but it's very unusual to try to apply both at the webserver tier.

Comment: I don't think I confuse them. First I need to know WHO you are (authentication), before I decide WHAT you can do (authorization). And establishing identity early makes it easy to pass identity along. "Usual" is for others :-). I have different back-end modules who all can inherit the web server's user information, so the web tier needs to establish identity (for OAuth that's a slight "abuse" of the idea, but could serve the purpose).

Comment: Actually - establishing identity ALWAYS has been a task of the container (at least in Java land), so using your code is the bad idea here :-) Authorization also is better served declarative, but that's usual a combination of groups/roles and checks for them in code